# Как сделать анимацию на js и css, чтобы одно фото накрывало другое при движение мыши

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

Все привет. Не пойму как сделать чтобы одно фото накрывало другое при движение мыши. Понятно, что объясняю не понятно, поэтому пример:https://aaa-sitrak.ru/trade-in. Может есть готовое решение?

Comment: [How to create a “Before & After” image slider with CSS and JS](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-before-after-image-slider-with-css-and-js-a609d9ba77bf)

Comment: @Simon, спасибо - то что нужно. Можете сделать как ответ, я приму